# Looking for Bittorrent client whose IPv6 support can be enabled or disabled and is not Azureus

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, bittorrent

Just as title explains: I'm looking for Bittorrent client whose IPv6 support can be enabled or disabled and is not Azureus. It needs to work on Windows, but GNU/Linux support (even if Wine is needed) is a plus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[utorrent](http://www.utorrent.com/) has been the defacto bitorrent client of choice for many people (its also the official bitorrent client these days) - it has a button that i presume turns on and off ipv6 support (and works with teredo), is lightweight, and runs on wine.

Comment: Can you tell me where that button is? I switched from it to Azureus because I couldn't find the button.

Comment: Are you quite sure about the button? I just checked the preferences interface again and was unable to locate the button.

Comment: my bad, its  'install ipv6/teredo' button in general that i confused with it. There's an advanced option for disabling incoming ipcgv6 in the advanced tab

Comment: Thanks! The option in my version is called net.disable_incoming_ipv6.

Comment: i run utorrent on another computer and i had to go over and check ;p